# Do not know how to say male(X) not equal to female(X)

Tags: prolog

I have the following code in prolog.

```
male(X).
female(X).
child(X,Y).

mother(X,Y) :- female(X), child(Y,X).
```

this code outputs yes even when I test it as
male(X), mother(X,Y).

I don't how should I code male(X) is not equal to female(X) in this?

I have tried mother(X,Y) :- female(X), !, +male(X), child(Y,X). But this doesn't work.

Comment: `male(X).` means everyone is male. `female(X).` means everyone is female. What are you trying to do with those?

Comment: I know that is the problem. this code is not able to differentiate between male and female. Basically I use male and female to write rules for mother and father etc.

Comment: Your definition of `mother/2` cannot make sense if the predicates it calls do not make sense. Your attention is on the wrong level. The definition of `mother/2` is fine. It is your definitions of `male/1`, `female/1` and `child/2` which are incorrect, as @aschepler says. You should probably have facts for those instead of rules: `male(abraham)`, `female(sarah)`, `child(isaac,sarah)`.